# How to get text between td tags using regular expressions

Tags: c#, html, regex

I want to get the text between the td tags of an html page..

The following is a short snippet of the html code of the page

> ```
>  <tr align="right"><td>989</td><td>Kristoffer</td><td>Shameka</td>
>
>  <tr align="right"><td>990</td><td>Lazaro</td><td>Deirdre</td>
>
>  <tr align="right"><td>991</td><td>Torey</td><td>Shantell</td>
>
>  <tr align="right"><td>992</td><td>Bill</td><td>Cherish</td>
>
>  <tr align="right"><td>993</td><td>Bruno</td><td>Linsey</td>
>
>  <tr align="right"><td>994</td><td>Genaro</td><td>Hali</td>
>
>  <tr align="right"><td>995</td><td>Waylon</td><td>Tarah</td>
>
>  <tr align="right"><td>996</td><td>Brittany</td><td>Annemarie</td>
> ```
>
> . . . and so on.

I want to extract the individual cell values(eg:for the first column 989, Kristoffer and Shameka) using REGULAR EXPRESSIONS.. Help!

Comment: Why?!  DOM was written so that you wouldn't have to parse an html document with regular expressions!  Why you think you need to do it this way?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use regex? Do you know that this will indeed be the format of the HTML (always) and that it is well formed? If not, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583) to see why regex is a poor solution.

Comment: @Neil - How is DOM supposed to work in C#?

Comment: You cant! Use javascript/jQuery instead.

Comment: Agreed, this is a job for a DOM parser not regex.

Comment: You should totally drop that and use jQuery.

Comment: You don't want to use regex on xml. It's complicated, fragile and often horribly inefficient. Use a parser suitable to the environment you are working in.

Comment: @Oded, if you limit your options, then you'll work with a limited mindset.  The more important question is why he wants to do this, since it may save him a great deal of time and effort.

Comment: Please read and understand the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the input HTML is always going to have the correct and same structure or not, Regex is not the best solution for what you are doing - since HTML is not a regular language, Regex can be a bad solution, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583).

If you can't trust that the input is the same, you should use a HTML parse like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) which can handle malformed HTML and query its object model.

If you know the input has the same format all the time, in this case, with the input you have shown, you can and should use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to parse out the needed values.

```
myHtmlString.Split(new []{@"<tr align=""right""><td>", "</td><td>", "</td>" },
                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: -1:  Acceptable answer if no other options existed, though it hasn't yet been determined if this cannot be accomplished in a better way using javascript.

Comment: @Neil - The OP has not asked about javascript. The question was tagged  with C#.

Comment: I'm interested in solving his problem, not answering his question.

Comment: @Neil - And you are saying this answer does not solve his problem? How do you know?

Comment: I don't.  No attempts so far have been made to understand the problem in its entirety.  Might be an adequate answer had he explictly wrote that it must be done in C#.  I'll remove the -1 if you add something which suggests that if C# is the only language which can be used to fix the problem, then the following is the answer.

Comment: @Neil, you may not have noticed that the OP added the tag `C#` to his question, this explicitly implies that he wants an answer in C#. Oded is answering the question as asked, and apparently, to the satisfaction of the OP.

Comment: @Benjol - Neil wants to know the end goal of the OP in order to give the best possible solution. Seeing as the OP is not responding to any queries, I figured that something that will answer the question will do.

Comment: @Benjol, so what's the problem?  It seems the overall approval of his answer has outranked my disapproval.  It's not as if I stripped him of all upvotes and banned him from stackoverflow.  My point was simply that if I asked for the best way to implement a bubble sort on a million records, that at least someone say, "Perhaps bubble sort is not what you want, but in case you did..."